# Tab always calls first activity?

Tags: android, android-tabactivity

I have created `TabActivity` in `MainActivity`. I have 5 Activities. And set the `currentTab(2)` to it.
I mean i want to load the third tab as the launching Activity.

**Problem**

In the first Tab I am calling an `AsyncTask` on onCreate . It is calling whereas I have set the current Tab to third activity. I have tried different Approaches but can't find a solution. whatever value you set to the currentTab . All Tabs before that value are created. It may be the behaviour of TabActivity.

Please guide me an approach to solve such an issue.

```
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity implements OnTabChangeListener
{
TabHost tabHost;

// ImageView rate_img;

ImagesCache cache;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

cache = ImagesCache.getInstance();

cache.initializeCache();

tabHost = getTabHost();

this.setDefaultTab(2);

/*rate_img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.rate_us);
rate_img.setOnClickListener(this);*/

// Tab for Highlights
TabSpec highlightsspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Highlights");

highlightsspec.setIndicator("");

Intent highlightsIntent = new Intent(this,Highlights.class);

highlightsspec.setContent(highlightsIntent);

tabHost.addTab(highlightsspec);



// Tab for Live Score
TabSpec livescorespec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Live Score");

livescorespec.setIndicator("");

Intent livescoreIntent = new Intent(this,Livescore.class);

livescorespec.setContent(livescoreIntent);

tabHost.addTab(livescorespec);


//Tab for Live

TabSpec livespec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Live");

livespec.setIndicator("");

Intent liveIntent=new Intent(this,Live.class);

livespec.setContent(liveIntent);

tabHost.addTab(livespec);


// Tab for News

TabSpec newspec=tabHost.newTabSpec("News");

newspec.setIndicator("");

Intent newsIntent=new Intent(this,News.class);

newspec.setContent(newsIntent);

tabHost.addTab(newspec);

// Tab for Live Channels

TabSpec livechannelsTabSpec=tabHost.newTabSpec("Live Channels");

livechannelsTabSpec.setIndicator("");

Intent livechannelsIntent=new Intent(this,Livechannels.class);

livechannelsTabSpec.setContent(livechannelsIntent);

tabHost.addTab(livechannelsTabSpec);


//////////////////////////////Add Spaces To Tabs //////////////////////////////////

TabWidget tabWidget = (TabWidget) findViewById(android.R.id.tabs);
final int tabChildrenCount = tabWidget.getChildCount();
View currentView;
for (int i = 0; i < tabChildrenCount; i++)
{
currentView = tabWidget.getChildAt(i);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams currentLayout =
(LinearLayout.LayoutParams) currentView.getLayoutParams();
currentLayout.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
tabWidget.requestLayout();

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();

getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);

int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;

int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;


if((width <= 1600 && width > 800) || (height <= 2600 && height > 1280))
{
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).getLayoutParams().height = 230;

tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).getLayoutParams().height = 230;

tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).getLayoutParams().height = 230;

tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).getLayoutParams().height = 230;

tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(4).getLayoutParams().height = 230;
}
else
{
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).getLayoutParams().height = 140;

tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).getLayoutParams().height = 140;

tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).getLayoutParams().height = 140;

tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).getLayoutParams().height = 140;

tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(4).getLayoutParams().height = 140;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.highlights_unselected);
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.scores_unselected);
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.live_selected);
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.news_unselected);
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(4).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.channels_unselected);


tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);

tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
}


@Override
public void onTabChanged(String tabId)
{

int index = tabHost.getCurrentTab();

if(index == 0)
{
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.highlights_selected);
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.scores_unselected);
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.live_unselected);
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.news_unselected);
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(4).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.channels_unselected);
}
else if(index == 1)
{
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.highlights_unselected);
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.scores_selected);
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.live_unselected);
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.news_unselected);
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(4).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.channels_unselected);
}
else if(index == 2)
{
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.highlights_unselected);
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.scores_unselected);
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.live_selected);
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.news_unselected);
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(4).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.channels_unselected);
}

else if(index == 3)
{
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.highlights_unselected);
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.scores_unselected);
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.live_unselected);
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.news_selected);
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(4).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.channels_unselected);
}

else if(index == 4)
{
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.highlights_unselected);
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.scores_unselected);
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.live_unselected);
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.news_unselected);
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(4).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.channels_selected);
}

} }
```

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: TabActivity is deprecated, use fragments instead

Comment: Use ViewPager to contain and maintain swiping between your fragments. pass the fragmentmanager to viewpager adapter. if you need tabs use something like viewpager indicator!

Answer (score 0):

First upon i would like to say that tab activity is depricated from android so it will be good if you use fragment,view pager,swipable tab it will give you more flexibility and control over the tab related requirement

use `tabhostOBJ.setCurrentTab(2);`

method in your tabActivity where you initialised your object related to tabs

**2** is the index number of your tab so it will set your current tab with third activity
hope it will help you

Comment: tell me some tutorials where i can create swipable tab using viewpager and fragment . I have learned about fragmentPagerAdapter . Is it helpful for creating a tabActivity like scenario